# UserForms and Loop with Word Range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a userform that I'm using, that allows a user to input a number. I will use this number to expand a selection by that many paragraphs.

The idea is, I have a document with hundreds of definitions.  These start with "[word] - means [etc.]", so I can look for "means", select the paragraph that it is in, then ask the user if they want to add this paragraph to the Index.

Occasionally, definitions are spread over two paragraphs.  I'd like the user to be able to input "2", and have the two paragraphs selected.

I've got the form working, *except* I'm stuck on how to loop this.  I'm not too familiar with Word VBA (but am with Excel), so am not sure where I'm going wrong.

The focus is the `Case 0` block, see my comments.  This is where I want to expand the selection by X paragraphs.

```
Sub find_Definitions()
Dim defText As String, findText$
Dim oRng    As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
Dim myForm As frmAddDefinition
Set myForm = New frmAddDefinition

Dim addDefinition$, expandParagraph&
expandParagraph = 1

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
findText = InputBox("What text would you like to search for?")

With oRng.Find
    .Text = findText
    While .Execute
Start_Find:
    Set rng = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rng.Select
        defText = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        myForm.Show
        Select Case myForm.Tag
            Case 0 ' Expand the paragraph selection
                expandParagraph = InputBox("How many paragraphs to extend selection?")
                rng.MoveEnd unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=expandParagraph
                rng.Select
                defText = rng
                ' Here I want to ask if this is okay, or to expand again
                ' ?????

                ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=defText, entryautotext:=defText
            Case 1 ' No, do not add to the index
                ' do nothing
            Case 2 ' Yes, add to index
                ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=defText, entryautotext:=defText
            Case 3 ' Cancel, exit the sub
                MsgBox ("Exiting macro")
                GoTo lbl_Exit
        End Select
    Wend
End With

lbl_Exit:
Unload myForm
Set myForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Edit: Using the code above, it will select the highlighted text:

[image]

But, I want to include the "Way One" and "Way Two", so I would like to enter, via that `inputBox` 2, to extend the selection down two paragraphs.  How can I get it to do that? This is where I am stuck.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I thought about this overnight, but it's still no clearer this morning... What do you mean by "...except I'm stuck on how to loop this"? Why would it need a loop? Are you familiar with Word's Range.MoveEnd function that will let you extend a Range by a specified number of "units"?

Comment: @cindyMeister - I'm used to excel so I may need to adjust the wording. If the user wants to extend the selection, they will type a number in. My idea is to then "loop back" to the start, using the updated `expandParagraph` to set the `defTrxt`. (On mobile now but will update my op later, hopefully with better clarification).

Comment: @CindyMeister - I've edited my post, with a screenshot.  Hopefully it's more clear now.  I've tried `Selection.MoveEnd unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2` and that seems to work, so I'll feather it in and see.  But I think you have the answer! Now, I just need to figure how to ask the user if the *new* selection is okay, or to expand again. How can I loop back to that question?  Use `GoTo`?

Comment: Our posts crossed... I'd maybe put it in a Do...Loop While and check Not `IsNumeric(nrParas)` as well as >1 in case they type in something like "none" or "no more".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in Word if you want to extend a Range to include "something more" you generally use one of the `Range.MoveEnd` method (there's also a `MoveStart` method). In Word, a Range is a group of contiguous characters, running from left-to-right, top-to-bottom in the document. Every Range has a start and an end point; these can be the same position in the document. Think of it like a selection, except a Range is not visible and you can have as many as you like. (So similar to Excel in this respect.) If you want to extend a selection you hold the Shift key and type the Arrow keys; in the object model you use `MoveEnd` (and `MoveStart`).

These methods take two parameters: `Unit` and `Count`.

`Unit` lets you specify the "something" (character, word, paragraph, story...) as a `WdUnits` enum. `Count` lets you specify how many "somethings" to extend the end by.

The following code snippet demonstrates how I understand you want to interact with the user. It starts from the current selection, instead of using Find, but that shouldn't be a problem for you

```
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim nrParas As String

Set rng = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
Do
    nrParas = InputBox("How many more paragraphs do you need?")
    If Not IsNumeric(nrParas) Then Exit Sub 'Or Exit Do if other code follows
    If CLng(nrParas) > 1 Then  '>1 because 1 is a given
        rng.MoveEnd wdParagraph, CLng(nrParas) - 1 '-1 because 1 is a given
    End If
    'for visual verification
    rng.Select
Loop While IsNumeric(nrParas) And nrParas > 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your excellent explanation!  I was able to add this into the code. See the edited code in my OP).  One final question is how can I prompt the user if this new selection is okay, before moving on in the loop?